# Is fight always of a negative connotation?

Tags: synonyms

Is fight always of a negative connotation? Is there a better one that conveys the same points with a more positive meaning? As in “fighting for change”?

Comment: You're welcome. You revised your question while I was composing my earlier comment, prompting me to extend my comment to what you see now. I'm transferring my comment to an answer. Tidying up the comments now. We can delete our own comments by hovering over the comment and clicking the 'x' that appears.

Answer (score 1):

No, the connotation isn't *always* negative.

*Fight* has a connotation of *activity*, but whether it suggests something positive or negative depends on several elements of context, including the text, the author, and the listener.

With reference to your example: "fighting for change" would likely sound negative to someone who doesn't want change, and positive to someone who does.